# Is there any way of using "before_filter :authenticate_user!" together with a boolean in the table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using **Devise**. I added a `admin` boolean column to my `users` table:

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :admin
  end
end
```

I want only allow admins to destroy users.
Devise's `before_filter :authenticate_user!` works by only enabling signed in users to perform an action. Is there a way of adding something to `:authenticate_user` so that only users with `:admin => true` can perform an action (en.g. destroy action)?

Comment: Somewhat related question: if you're using devise, why don't you create a separate admin role?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
before_filter :is_admin?

def is_admin?
  if current_user.admin?
    true
  else
    render :text => 'Who are you to doing this? :)'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but to make this work I have to create  destroy action? Can I use Devise's `new_registration, :action => "destroy"`?

Comment: before_filter :is_admin?, :only => :destroy   ?

Comment: I think I tried that. But it complains that there is no destroy action (I guess the only way to customize its `new_registration` controller?)

Comment: You can use any operation you whish after :is_admin? returns true

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend to put all your admin actions underneath an admin namespace within your application and to use a gem such as CanCanCan for the authorization.

For instance, the action to delete a `User` object would be in the `UsersController` underneath the `Admin` namespace. The controller would basically be defined like this:

```
 class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
   def destroy
     user = User.find(params[:id])
     user.destroy
     redirect_to admin_users_path
   end
 end
```

The `Admin::BaseController` referenced here is the controller which provides a base for your admin namespace. It should authorize users, like this:

```
 class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_user!
   before_filter :authorize_admin

   def authorize_admin
     authorize! :manage, :all
   end
 end
```

The `authorize!` helper would be provided by `CanCan`. I won't repeat what the [CanCan wiki already covers](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) in regard to setting up the `Ability` class. CanCan is also covered in a [great screencast by the author](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

It's inside this `Ability` class that you should be checking for that boolean field and then letting CanCan deal with the authorization.

To actually route to this new `Admin::UsersController`, define this inside your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

If you don't want to use CanCanCan, there's also [Pundit](https://rubygems.org/gems/pundit).

Comment: Thanks! In the code above is that controller for a new model called `Admin`?

Comment: No, there is no `Admin` model. `Admin` is just a namespace. I missed mentioning the namespace stuff in the answer the first time. I'll add it now.

Comment: It is better to use CanCanCan instead of CanCan. CanCan is no longer supported by author.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended not to modify behaviour of third party methods such as :authenticate_user!. You can easily achieve by setting up the second filter, which may be as simple as the following :

```
before_filter :ensure_admin, :only => [:new, :create]

private

def ensure_admin
 unless current_user && current_user.admin?
   render :text => "You are not authorised to perform this action", :status => :unauthorized
 end
end
```

Comment: Can I use Devise's `new_registration, :action => "destroy"`?